# vscode win10 access denied to GitHub Repo

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, ssh, windows-10

## Problem

```
> git fetch --all
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: could not fetch origin
```

### Settings `Win10`

`/Users/xxxx/.gitconfig`

```
[core]
    editor = \"C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin\\code\" --wait
[user]
    name = xxxxxxxxx
    email = xxxxxxxxxxxx
    signingkey = xxxxxxxxx
[init]
    defaultBranch = main
[safe]
    directory = F:/xxxxxxxx
[credential]
    helper = store
```

### User SSH Config

```
Host *
  ForwardAgent yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  Compression yes

Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
```

### User/xxx/.ssh/agent.env

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-wvlNI9wNQpqQ/agent.221; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=222; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 222;
```

### VSCODE `settings.json`

```
,,,
 "git.alwaysSignOff": true,
  "git.autofetch": "all",
  "git.confirmEmptyCommits": true,
  "git.enableCommitSigning": true,
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "git.followTagsWhenSync": true,
  "git.postCommitCommand": "sync",
  "git.pruneOnFetch": true,
  "git.rebaseWhenSync": true,
  "git.showPushSuccessNotification": true,
  "npm.enableRunFromFolder": true,
  "npm.scriptExplorerAction": "run",
  "npm.enableTouchbar": true,
```

### Caveats

I have Win10 services running for

1. SSH ( Client / Server ) [ Auto ]
2. SSH-Agent [ Auto ]
3. .basrc

```
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2=agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

Windows Update keeps all this updated. I did a test ssh connection to Github.

```
Shell integration activated
PS F:\yada-bootstrap-11ty> ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.3' to the list of known hosts.
Hi inetbiz! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I've been trying to make this work for weeks. I've googled my hear out. I'm sure there is a setting I've missed to make this work given I can connect to Github from the *CLI**?

[image: Github Keys]Problem

### SSH -vvvT

```
> git fetch --all
OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/denve/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/denve/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /c/Users/denve/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.114.4] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 4 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/denve/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 2
debug1: identity file /c/Users/denve/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-65a6644c
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-65a6644c
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/denve/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/denve/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:280zP2iWmGeX6MBHy9E/GUBHbbQgg9yjcZuE2dvsvXk explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/denve/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:280zP2iWmGeX6MBHy9E/GUBHbbQgg9yjcZuE2dvsvXk explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /c/Users/denve/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:280zP2iWmGeX6MBHy9E/GUBHbbQgg9yjcZuE2dvsvXk explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with ECDSA SHA256:280zP2iWmGeX6MBHy9E/GUBHbbQgg9yjcZuE2dvsvXk
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 SHA256:280zP2iWmGeX6MBHy9E/GUBHbbQgg9yjcZuE2dvsvXk
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: could not fetch origin
```

### Subsystem Edit SSH

From: https://serverfault.com/questions/888350/windows-10-ssh-disable-password-authentication

I edited `c:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config (aka %PROGRAMDATA%\ssh\sshd_config)`

I added:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

OS restarted. Same git output as above.^

## System's `sshd_config`

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 6
MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
UseLogin no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication no

AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

Added `UseLogin no`

Comment: I don't use Windows, so this is a bit of a shot in the dark, but: Windows comes with one ssh; Git-for-Windows comes with *another* ssh; and the two use different file locations. So it's possible that you're getting the "wrong" ssh command used. For Git (but perhaps not VSCode, which has yet its own private weirdness) you can use `core.sshCommand` or `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to point Git to the Windows ssh instead of the Git one, once you have the Windows one working.

Comment: It's definitely helpful to set `GIT_TRACE` here as well and try setting the ssh that Git runs to `ssh -vvv` so that you can observe ssh attempting to connect, although how you do that within VSCode (and whether it hides the ssh output or gets confused by the verbose output), I have no idea.

Comment: @torek I modified ssh_config and edited changed .gitconfig. I updated and appended to question, the output.

Comment: Interesting: "debug1: Server accepts key". But then it goes on to say that it needs the passphrase. It can't get the passphrase (no tty interaction allowed) so it fails at that point. So for some reason the ssh agent wasn't able to hand over the private key.

Comment: Could you run and attach the output for: 
 `$ ssh -T git@github.com`
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection